# Google mapping: initMap is not a function error in 5.29.1

Tags: civievent, location, google

Using Drupal 7. Maps do not display in CiviEvent, although they display fine on the Drupal site.

Console displays the below. Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

> message: "initMap is not a function" ​ name: "InvalidValueError" ​
> stack:
> "ne@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:70:72\n_.oe@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:70:182\nTj@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:143:238\nUj/<@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:143:125\npromise
> callback*Uj@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:143:107\ngoogle.maps.Load@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:14:12\n@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:257:436\n@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&callback=initMap:257:448\n"

Comment: can you clear civicrm cache and delete template_c directory? Also do check Resource URL again

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep - no difference. I'm not sure what I'd be looking for when it comes to the Resource URL - it looks like the default. I did miss the beginning of the console error, though - it's:

Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { message: "initMap is not a function", etc.

Perhaps that helps? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I'm also seeing NoApiKeys and SensorNotRequired warnings. Again, I know the key is working because it works fine in Drupal. Ugh.

Comment: I had the same error and warnings, my issue was missing latitude and longitude values (geocoding wasn't happening), the civi logs were helpful.